# Having trouble wrapping functions in the linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, wrapper

I've written a LKM that implements Trusted Path Execution (TPE) into your kernel:

https://github.com/cormander/tpe-lkm

I run into an occasional kernel OOPS (describe at the end of this question) when I define **WRAP_SYSCALLS** to 1, and am at my wit's end trying to track it down.

A little background:

Since the LSM framework doesn't export its symbols, I had to get creative with how I insert the TPE checking into the running kernel. I wrote a find_symbol_address() function that gives me the address of any function I need, and it works very well. I can call functions like this:

```
int (*my_printk)(const char *fmt, ...);
my_printk = find_symbol_address("printk");
(*my_printk)("Hello, world!\n");
```

And it works fine. I use this method to locate the **security_file_mmap**, **security_file_mprotect**, and **security_bprm_check** functions.

I then overwrite those functions with an *asm* jump to my function to do the TPE check. The problem is, the currently loaded LSM will no longer execute the code for it's hook to that function, because it's been totally hijacked.

Here is an example of what I do:

```
int tpe_security_bprm_check(struct linux_binprm *bprm) {

    int ret = 0;

    if (bprm->file) {
            ret = tpe_allow_file(bprm->file);
            if (IS_ERR(ret))
                    goto out;
    }

#if WRAP_SYSCALLS
    stop_my_code(&cs_security_bprm_check);

    ret = cs_security_bprm_check.ptr(bprm);

    start_my_code(&cs_security_bprm_check);
#endif

    out:

    return ret;
}
```

Notice the section between the **#if WRAP_SYSCALLS** section (it's defined as 0 by default). If set to 1, the LSM's hook is called because I write the original code back over the *asm* jump and call that function, but I run into an occasional kernel OOPS with an "invalid opcode":

```
invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP 
RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8117b006>]  [<ffffffff8117b006>] security_bprm_check+0x6/0x310
```

I don't know what the issue is. I've tried several different types of locking methods (see the inside of **start/stop_my_code** for details) to no avail. To trigger the kernel OOPS, write a simple bash while loop that endlessly starts a backgrounded "ls" command. After a minute or so, it'll happen.

I'm testing this on a RHEL6 kernel, also works on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (2.6.32 x86_64).

While this method has been the most successful so far, I have tried another method of simply copying the kernel function to a pointer I created with **kmalloc** but when I try to execute it, I get: *kernel tried to execute NX-protected page - exploit attempt? (uid: 0)*. If anyone can tell me how to kmalloc space and have it marked as executable, that would also help me solve the above problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.It seems, the beginning of `security_bprm_check()` is not restored completely before the function is called. The oops happens at `security_bprm_check+0x6`, i.e. right after the jump you placed there, so it seems, some part of the jump is still there at that moment. I cannot say now why this can happen.

Take a look at the implementation of [Kernel Probes (KProbes)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/kprobes.c) on x86, it may give you some hints. See also the [description of KProbes](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kprobes.txt) for details. KProbes need to patch and restore almost arbitrary pieces of kernel code in a safe way to do their work.

2.Now to the other approach that you mentioned, concerning copying of the function. The following is a bit of a hack and would be frowned upon by the kernel developers but if there is no other way, this might help.

You can allocate memory to copy the functions to from the same area where the memory for the code of the kernel modules is allocated. That area should be executable by default. Again, KProbes use this trick to allocate their detour buffers.

Memory is allocated by `module_alloc()` function and freed by `module_free()`. These functions are of course not exported but you can find their addresses in the same way as you do for `security_file_mmap()`, etc. Just of curiosity, you are using `kallsyms_on_each_symbol()`, right?

If you allocate memory this way, this could also help avoid another not so obvious problem. On x86-64, the memory address areas available for kmalloc and for the modules' code are located quite far away from each other (see [Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt)), beyond the reach of any relative jump. If the memory is mapped to the modules' address area, you can use near relative jumps and calls to call the copied functions. A similar problem with RIP-relative addressing is also avoided this way.

**EDIT:** Note that on x86, if you copy some piece of code to a different memory area and you would like it to run there, some changes in that code may be necessary. At least you need to fixup the relative calls and jumps that transfer control outside of the copied code (e.g. the calls to another function, etc.) as well as the instructions with RIP-relative addressing.

Apart from that, there may be other structures in the code that need to be fixed up. For example, the compiler might have optimized some or even all `switch` statements to a jump via a table. That is, the addresses of the code blocks for each `case` are kept in a table in the memory and the switch variable is the index into that table. This way, instead of many comparisons, your module will execute something like `jmp <table_start>(%reg, N)` (N is the size of a pointer, in bytes). That is, just a jump to an address that is in the appropriate element of the table. Because such tables are created for the code before you copy it, fixup may be necessary otherwise such jumps will take the execution back to the original piece of code rather than the copied one.

Comment: find_symbol_address() First tries kallsyms_lookup_name() (if it's been loaded yet, which it obviously hasn't been the first time its ran). Second, it basically greps for the symbol in /proc/kallsyms, and then in /boot/System.map-$(uname -r). kallsyms_lookup_name() is found in /proc/kallsyms, so kallsyms_lookup_name() is used from then on (if it fails for some reason, falls back to the other methods). I'm able to use module_alloc(), but when I memcpy a function to the area, I either get "invalid opcode", "unable to handle kernel paging request", OR "general protection fault".

Comment: @Corey Henderson, OK, I see now. Thank you.

Comment: @Corey Henderson, as for the errors when copying, I have no idea why it fails. I use this trick in my project and it works fine. How do you find the length of the function to be copied? May be it has something to do with these errors...

Comment: For now I've been getting the length manually (look at System.map, subtract the address next to it). I've tried it with that both with and without *PAGE_SIZE. Is your project source published somewhere I can look at? I'm not the best C programmer, and with C, the devil is in the details. Perhaps update your answer with the relevant section of code that works for you?

Comment: The project I was talking about is not public yet but it will be. It will become an extension to KEDR framework (http://kedr.berlios.de/) that I maintain. For now, you can get the sources of the relevant component here: http://kedr.berlios.de/files/func_detour-01.tar.bz2 It is a kernel module that detects loading of another module, copies its functions to a buffer, adjusts the prologues and lets the module execute that way. See functions.* and detour_buffer.*.

Comment: Sorry, I put a broken link above. Here is the correct link: http://prdownload.berlios.de/kedr/func_detour-01.tar.bz2

Comment: After some in-depth examination of your code, I noticed the copy_and_fixup_insn() and how it steps through each instruction, does the memcpy, and "shifts" relative addresses (rather than memcpy the whole function over verbatim). So I wrote my own function that does simple arithmetic (calls no external code) and did the memcpy of it into a pointer and called the pointer, it worked. But when I do a memcpy of a function that makes other calls, I run into the opcode/page request/etc problems. So I assume I need to do this fixup thing along with the memcpy. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you need to fix up all relative calls and jumps that lead outside of the copied function as well as the instructions that use RIP-relative addressing on x86-64. One thing I did not do properly there is handling of indirect jumps using the jump table (`jmp <table_start>(%reg, N)`). The compiler may use these to optimize switch statements. You may also need to find such jumps and their jump tables and fixup these too, otherwise the jump will lead to the original function.

Comment: Thank you. Your input has been very helpful.