# How do you find the symbol of a specific C function when no symbols are loaded in user mode?

Tags: c, symbols

The following code is mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434701/having-trouble-wrapping-functions-in-the-linux-kernel).

```
int (*my_printk)(const char *fmt, ...);
my_printk = find_symbol_address("printk");
(*my_printk)("Hello, world!\n");
```

How does the OP find the symbol address if the LSM framework doesn't export its symbols? The OP's question is in kernel mode; I am curious how to do it in user mode.

Comment: What do you need to do this in user mode for? It is possible, but in user space you don't have the problem of access to functions that aren't exported. When you link against a shared library, you know all of its functions from that library's header file at compile time. You can then just call the function. You can't always do this in kernel space, hence the hacky code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linked-to question is very different than userspace: because the kernel maintains a complete symbol table (see `kernel/module.c` function `lookup_symbol`), it isn't very difficult to scan the table and look for a specific symbol, find its address, and perform the fairly hacky interpositioning he is performing. (I understand his reasoning, but its a pity he didn't just make his source a patch that could be applied to distribution kernels or even included into the mainline kernel tree. Fair enough, his code, his time, his playground, but it does mean he gets to do some pretty hacky things.)

User mode is a little different; if the symbols aren't available, they're just not available. The kernel developers went to some effort to emulate the case of "having symbols available" that is common in userspace, and if you've `strip(1)`ed your code, they're gone.

Comment: Once the non-hacky code is solid (the TPE portion) I'll submit it upstream. But i'd rather have a time tested module that works so I can say "its been working for some time" rather then it go into the kernel brand new. Also, this  works on people who have vendor lock-in now, and dont have to say "you have to wait till your distro upgrades the kernel", which in the EL space can be many years.

Comment: @Corey, hehe, I've been in the position of needing to provide a module that Just Works with vendor-provided kernels. Annoying. :( But several months deployment with "good code" will carry more weight with kernel developers than several months deployment with symbol hackery. Best of luck -- they can be a prickly bunch. :)

Comment: Thanks :) this will also be part of a project (not yet published) that is a rootkit that is an anti-rootkit. Wipe the symbol table, implement TPE, relocate commonly hijacked syscalls, etc. Basically do as many of the things in the grsecurity patch as possible that a code insertion hot-patch method can do. As far as pushing TPE upstream, I haven't even decided which way is best. I've been having problems implementing it with LSM and have it play ball with other LSMs. Maybe I'll eventually get it right.